# google map api key restriction for multiple websites

Tags: api

In the google developer console you can restrict your api key for a domain or an ip range. Problem is, we have like 500 Websites using the same api key for google map api.

How can i restrict the key so only our websites can use it?

I've tried it with a IP Range but it didn't work out.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent unauthorized access from websites that are essentially stealing from your quota?

Comment: zandermar18, exactly

Comment: Can you remind me if you are just using an API key or using a combination of clientID and clientSecret and if they are stored on the client or server?

Comment: We are just using an API Key for the google Map API an GeoCoding API. We don't use any client IDs or something. Is this possibly the solution?

Comment: I see. You mentioned that the IP Range restriction didn't work. Can you elaborate more on that?